# jQuery submit form using textarea onkeypress Enter

Tags: jquery, textarea

I want to submit a form with **textarea onKeyPress Enter** and **without refreshing page**.
Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#msg').keydown(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            //alert('it works until this line');
            $("#myform").validate({
                submitHandler: function(form) {
                    $.post('submit.php', $("#myform").serialize(), function(data) {
                        $('#results').html(data);
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

```
<form name="myform" id="myform" action="" method="POST"><textarea name="msg" id="msg"></textarea></form>
```

Those codes didn't work, anyone can help me to solve this problem?

Comment: I don't know that validation plugin but maybe calling validate() doesn't submit the form but rather prepare it to be used with submitHandler.

Comment: I redacted my last response. Why would you use a textarea and override the enter key? The point in a textarea is that you can enter multiple lines by using the enter key. Did you want to use a text input instead?

Comment: Does your form validate ? Do you get any error message (related to the ajax call for instance ? Have you checked the console ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#textarea_handle").keypress(function(e)
    {

        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);

        if (code == 13)
        {

            $('#form_handle').submit();

        }

    });
```